# Prevent Struts 2 validation for specific action

Tags: java, validation, struts2, annotations, struts2-interceptors

I have two actions in different action class.
Two actions are :

- 1st action (fields : email)
- 2nd action (fields : email,firstName)

Both are using `User` object to validate fields

```
@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
```

and binding validation properties in `User` class as

```
@RequiredStringValidator(key="global.emptyemail")
    @EmailValidator(key="global.invalidemail")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
```

Now problem is it works fine for `1st action` (which doesn't include `firstName` as field), for 2nd action which includes `firstName` field I provided

```
@RequiredStringValidator(key="global.firstNameRequired", fieldName = "firstName")
    @RegexFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, key="global.SpecialCharacter",
            regexExpression = "[^&%$#@!~]*", fieldName = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
```

with this 1st action stopped working, might be it is going to search `firstName` which is not present

So, how to make validation for `firstName` to be done only for 2nd action ? (not for 1st action)

Comment: Did you apply this annotations on the class or on the method of the class&

Comment: on the method of the class

Comment: In xml validation you can use `context` parameter for that: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/visitor-validator.html.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following parameter to the action configuration, this allows to prevent to run validators on other actions/methods rather than the one is called.

```
interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
```

Comment: not working..i tried this putting in both actions one by one and also at the same time

Comment: struts version 2.3.16